# ASP.Net MVC Entity Framework and relationships

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get my head around ASP.Net MVC having come from a Web Forms background.

I've got a MySQL database with 2 entities:

```
artwork - id(PK), artistid(FK), name...
artist - id(PK), artist, website...
```

I've created an ADO.Net Entity Data Model using this database and ArtistController.cs and ArtworkController.cs, which has created the corresponding views.

Now when I access http://localhost:49664/Artwork, the page displays a list of all the rows in the artwork table, however, it displays the artistid.  How would I go about displaying the artist's name instead?

**UPDATE:**

In the database, the field in the artist table is named 'artist' but when creating the Entity Data Model, Visual Studio has named it as 'artist1'.

I've tried '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.artist.artist)' but that still displays the artist id.

Artwork class:

```
public partial class artwork
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> artistId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> editionId { get; set; }

    public virtual artist artist { get; set; }
    public virtual edition edition { get; set; }
}
```

Artist class:

```
public partial class artist
{
    public artist()
    {
        this.artworks = new HashSet<artwork>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string artist1 { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<artwork> artworks { get; set; }
}
```

Artwork Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var artworks = db.artworks.Include(a => a.artist).Include(a => a.edition);
    return View(artworks.ToList());
}
```

Artwork view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<myflatfile.artwork>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.artist1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.title)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.artist.artist1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What is the artist1 column? Based on info provided it should be @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.artist.name)

Comment: @SteveGreene The artist1 column is the artist's name field I believe. The ADO.Net Entity Data Model created by Visual Studio has named it 'artist1' for some reason instead of 'artist'.

Comment: right, you can't have a field name with the same name as the class. you might want to rename it 'name' to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if I got you, you are using entity framework then every artwork entity has the object of artist it is refer to in db.
so all you need to do is: 
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.artist.name)`

**Edit:**
I've a workaround in my mind, you can manipulate the object in Artwork controller before pass it to the view and add the the name and whatever you need

Comment: The 'artist' entity has no 'name' field. In the database, it's named 'artist' and the ADO.Net Entity Data Model created by Visual Studio has named it 'artist1'.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared something for you with notepad and i am a bit sleepy. So, if it has error or errors, write me again for that.

**Artwork class:**

```
public class artworklist
{
   public List<artwork> ArtworkModelList { get; set; }
}


public partial class artwork
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> artistId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> editionId { get; set; }

    public virtual artist artist { get; set; }
    public virtual edition edition { get; set; }
}
```

**Artist Class:**

```
public class artistlist
{
    public List<artist> ArtistModelList { get; set; }
}

public partial class artist
{
    public artist()
    {
        this.artworks = new HashSet<artwork>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string artist1 { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<artwork> artworks { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Art.Model.ArtistList



@if (null == Model || null == Model.ArtistModelList || 0 == Model.ArtistModelList.Count)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>There is no data.</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var art in Model.ArtistModelList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@@@art.artist</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Art()
   {
           var model = new ArtistList();

            using (var dbContext = new ArtContext())
            {
                var artists = (from m in dbContext.Artists
                             select new ArtistModel
                             {
                                 ID = m.ID,
                                 Artist1 = m.Artist1,
                                 Website = m.Website,
                                 Artworks = m.Artworks
                             }).ToList();

                model.ArtistModelList = artists;
                return View(model);
            }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Art(Artist model)
    {

            Artist art = new Artist();

            art.ID = model.ID,
            art.Artist1 = model.Artist1,
            art.Website = model.Website,
            art.Artworks = model.Artworks

            using (ArtContext db = new ArtContext())
            {

                db.Artists.Add(art);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("*****", "*****"); // where you want (action,url)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `DisplayFor` in a wrong way. It is used as a template to display the data [(ref)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390(v=vs.118).aspx).

Should be used as

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.artist.artist1)
```

But you have a List for the model. So I'd suggest create a partial view with `artwork` as model.

```
@model artwork
<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.artist.artist1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.title)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

then render this partial view inside your for loop in the main view

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    Html.RenderPartial("partialViewName", item);
}
```

Or, if you want to keep it simple, just render the properties directly
in the main view

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.artist.artist1
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.artist.artist1.title
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```